# Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
 session_start();

 $username = "root";
 $password = "password";
 $database = "meipolytechnic";
 mysql_connect('localhost', $username,$password);
 @mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());


 $username=$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
 $query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$username."'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

  mysql_close();

   $rows = array();

   while($r = mysql_fetch_row($result))

   {
    $rows[] = $r[0];
   }

   echo ($rows['rollno']);

   ?>
```

i want to retrieve only the logged in users roll no from users table in database

when i run this code

and log in as foo

i get the following stuff

Unknown column 'foo' in 'where clause'

Comment: Go to php.net and read about `mysql_error()` then fix that.

Comment: If you're using sessions then you need to have `session_start()` at the top of each page that is using them. Also change `mysql_error("error")` to `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Try not to use 'mysql_' functions anymore, it's deprecated and should not be used in new applications. Its use is strongly discouraged, in the future your script wil fail.
Instead use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).
If choosing PDO, please read [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) tutorial for an easy manual with examples.

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions, they're deprecated and will be removed in one of the next PHP versions!

Comment: You should use the mysqli class (or methods) or the PDO class.

Also you should escape your session, or with PDO bind some paramters.

WHERE username = @Username;  (PDO)
or 
WHERE username = " . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION[MM_Username] . "  (MySQLi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be `session_start()` at the top of the page

query need to change as

```
$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."' ";
```

**EDIT**

Please try something before posting a question here. Please google or go through www.w3school.com for clearing this kind of issues. Make a good knowledge about arrays and mysql connection. And mysql_query function won't work latest PHP version.

Please try following code.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
   $rows[] = $r[0];
}
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: mr.Shafeeq now getting Notice: Undefined index: rollno in

Answer (score 0):

To use an array inside a string you need to put a curly bracket before it and after it
so

```
$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = {$_SESSION['MM_Username']}";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
```

Comment: now getting this error Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MEIP\students.php on line 68
Array

Comment: @user2774977 Are you use you put the curly brackets and the single quote before and right after the array key?

Answer (score 0):

first start your session

```
session_start();
```

and Change your query like this...

```
$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
```

Comment: now getting this error Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MEIP\students.php on line 68
Array

Comment: @user2774977 change $_SESSION['MM_Username'] in the query... put ' quote

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 $query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = ".$_SESSION[MM_Username]." ";
```

And start session on same page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all start session using `start_session()`

then change your query:

```
$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
```

then change: 
`$num = mysql_num_rows($result); instead of $num = mysql_numrows($result);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
     $username=$_SESSION[MM_Username];
     $query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$username."'";
```

and start the session by using session_start()

and you have used two closing tags omit one make it like below

```
      echo ($rows['rollno']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occur when query goes false

May be becouse You have not start session, becouse if you dont have `session_start()`, then nothing will come in session variable... just try as

```
$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION[MM_Username]."'";
```

may this help you

Answer (score 0):

You must need to use session_start() before using $_SESSION variable in code.

So put below code at start,

```
session_start();
```

Then do some modification in query like,

```
$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
```